# Time limit exceeded error when using strlen()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strlen, time-limiting

The following code works as expected, this code prints the character that occurs the most number of times in a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    long int i,a[26]={0},m=0 ,c=0 ;
    char s[1000001] ;
    scanf("%s",s);
    for (i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
        a[s[i]-'a']++;
    }
    for ( i=0 ; i<26 ; i++)
        {
            if ( a[i] > m ) {       
            m = a[i] ;
            c = i ;
            }
        }

    printf("%c",'a' + c);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I use `strlen()` it causes a time limit error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    long int i,a[26]={0},m=0 ,c=0 ;
    char s[1000001] ;
    scanf("%s",s);
    for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        a[s[i]-'a']++;
    }
    for ( i=0 ; i<26 ; i++)
        {
            if ( a[i] > m ) {       
            m = a[i] ;
            c = i ;
            }
        }

    printf("%c",'a' + c);
    return 0;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to execute the strlen outside the for loop? Like site_t len = strlen(s) ? I think that it may be overriding something.

Comment: Does your string contain digits, punctuation, or special characters?  This seems unlikely, but subtracting `'a'` does make assumptions so that the index for `a` does not go negative.  When that happens, results are unpredictable.

Comment: Also, any change you have a debug library for `strlen()`?  That could incur quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: strlen is quite slow as it is forced to linearly scan the string to find the ending `\0`. Try as @prmottajr suggests, use strlen once before the for loop.

Comment: what happens when s[i] is not a lower case, printable, character?

Comment: Your use of `strlen` is inefficient -- but what is a "time limit error"? There are no restrictions in C on the execution time of a program. Are you running it in some environment that imposes such a restriction? Can you elaborate on that (preferably in the question)?

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf("%s",s);'  1) always check the returned code (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) while that input buffer 's[]' is quite large, it is still possible for the user to overflow the buffer.  suggest: 'scanf("%1000000s",s);' as this habit will pay large dividends in most programs in saved debug time.   Overflowing the input buffer is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: why call a system function when it is not needed?

Comment: amongst other things, code should not use 'magic' numbers beyond 0 and 1.  Therefore, strongly suggest that '26' be #define MAX_ALPHA_CHARS (26)  Then use the #define'd name wherever '26' is currently in the code.  A similar recommendation of the value '1000001'

Comment: @prmottajr i tried what you suggested and it's working fine thank you :) , @ Keith Thompson, it was during a contest and the time limit per test is 2 second !, and thanks everyone for your answers :)

Comment: @imad2px: The "@" has to be immediately followed by the name for the person to be notified.

Comment: Ok i missed that one ;) @KeithThompson :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char s[1000001]
```

Depending on OS, this might be too large for the stack. You should either allocate that dynamically using `malloc()` or at file-scope. Even if the stack is large enough, it is not good practice to have such large arrays on the stack.

Apart from that: `strlen()` is evaluated for each loop iteration, searching the string for the `NUL` terminator. For worst case (max. length), `strlen` is processed 1000000 times with searching all 1000001 positions of `s` (O(n**2)).

You should assign it to a variable outside the loop and use that to compare:

```
size_t slen = strlen(s);
for ( i = 0 ; i < slen ; i++ ) {
```

Or stick with the first version, that is fine, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
```

This code is calling `strlen(s)` function. It takes `O(n)` time complexity.

```
for (i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
```

This code calls no functions, so will be much quicker than the previous.

In first, checks length of `s` in every iteration of i and it takes `O(n)` to find the last 0, so it takes `O(n^2)`, the second case is `O(n)`.

Here, `O(n^2)` is a very large for calculation.

Comment: Function calls as such are not necessarily a problem, as they might be inlined (gcc for instance will heavily optimize many library functions using internal code).

Comment: I think strlen is the problem for time limit. @Olaf.

Comment: No kidding! Your answer, however implies it is just due to function calls, wheras it is because of the specifics of `strlen()`.

Comment: Am I right now?? @Olaf

Comment: I apparently cannot make my point clear. Perhaps, if you re-read my comments and think a little bit. The last edit, however, did not resolve anything. Just read this sentence of yours with open mind: "This code calls no functions, so will be much quicker than the previous." You actual expression is: "functions make code much slower." However, If I put the compare into a static function, the code most likely will not be a bit slower actually (unless compiled `-O0`), as the compiler will just inline the function without penalty.